# UI component in Gridlayout does not fit properly and they owerflow

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments, android-gridlayout

I am new at developing Android app.I have 4 EditText corresponding 4 TextView.but I have a problem with EditTexts,they dont fit properly.How can I handle this problem.Following is my xml layout file.Please help me,what is wrong.Thank you in advance.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.mobilecoursemanagementsystem.AddCourseActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:rowCount="5"
    android:columnCount="3">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Course Title"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"/>
    <!--android:layout_marginTop="10dp"-->

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/editTitle" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Course Code"
        android:id="@+id/txtCode"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/editCode" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Number of Student"
        android:id="@+id/txtNumberOfSts"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/editNumberOfSts" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Course Level"
        android:id="@+id/txtLevel"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/editLevel" />
</GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[click for Screenshoot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g74jfrrnbyriyki/layout-2014-11-25-194335.png?dl=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user layout_margins in your layout for every edittext

```
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
```

set whatever value you like for margin